# TalkBack accessibility StaggeredGridLayoutManager wrong focus order

Tags: android, android-layout, accessibility, talkback, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

So I'm trying to make my app accessible with the TalkBack function.
I'm trying to go over 22 items in a RecyclerView with layout manager StaggeredGridLayoutManager (Staggered GridView) and I expect the focus to go by the order like the item's position.

Expected example -

```
 | 1 | 2 |
 | 3 | 4 |
 | 5 | 6 |
 | 7 | 8 |
```

...

but the actual order is

1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,10,12,19,20,21,22
https://github.com/YoniBagi/StaggeredGridForAccessibility/blob/master/accessibility.gif

Now there are two issues here:

1. It does not go according to position order.
2. For some reason at item 12 it jumps to item 19 and skips those in the between.

Any solution or idea would be much appreciated.

Code:
https://github.com/YoniBagi/StaggeredGridForAccessibility/tree/master

Comment: The code you gave is insufficient to determine the problem. Please show the code where you try to do with the TalkBack

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution and wrote an article in the Medium

[link to solution](https://android.jlelse.eu/accessibility-and-staggered-grid-layout-8e01a753aada)

Good Luck!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make sure to read this page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for what is considered a good answer. "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there."

Comment: Not only a link but you gated it.